# NVidia Rapids: Non-Euclidean metric in cuml UMAP

Tags: python, nvidia, rapids, cuml

I am trying to use GPU (A100) to perform UMAP for speedup. I am facing problem as Euclidean metric does not seem to work for me at all but correlation/cosine are promising. However, the code I am using below seems to produce only Euclidean metric based computation on GPU while working well on CPU.

Tools:

```
cuml                      23.04.01        cuda11_py310_230421_g958186d07_0    rapidsai
libcuml                   23.04.01        cuda11_230421_g958186d07_0          rapidsai
libcumlprims              23.04.00        cuda11_230412_g7502d8e_0            nvidia
python                    3.10.11         he550d4f_0_cpython                  conda-forge
```

Relevant code:

```
def umap_cpu(ip_mat, n_components, n_neighbors, metric):
    import umap
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    ip_std = scaler.fit_transform(ip_mat)

    reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=n_components, n_neighbors=n_neighbors, metric=metric)
    umap_embed = reducer.fit_transform(ip_std)

    return umap_embed

def umap_gpu(ip_mat, n_components, n_neighbors, metric):
    import cuml
    from cuml.manifold import UMAP
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    ip_std = scaler.fit_transform(ip_mat)

    reducer = UMAP(n_components=n_components, n_neighbors=n_neighbors, metric=metric)
    umap_embed = reducer.fit_transform(ip_std)

    return umap_embed
```

Using `help` I noticed that other metrics are supported. However, I found an [old post](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/4816) that said otherwise in discussion.

> PR will allow the metric for the input KNN graph to be changed but the
> only supported target metrics currently remain to be categorical and
> Euclidean. We can support different target metrics (and we have issue
> open to support them) but they will require a slightly different
> objective function in the SGD. I do believe there's an error in the
> throwing of the Python exception (pointed out in this issue)

I would like to know if the implementation has been done for other metrics or the help tool shows wrong info.

> metric : string (default='euclidean').
> Distance metric to use. Supported distances are ['l1, 'cityblock',  'taxicab',
> 'manhattan', 'euclidean', 'l2', 'sqeuclidean', 'canberra', 'minkowski', 'chebyshev', 'linf', 'cosine', 'correlation', 'hellinger', 'hamming', 'jaccard'] Metrics that take arguments (such as minkowski) can have arguments  passed via the metric_kwds dictionary.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

The `metric` argument of cuml UMAP is used to specify the distance metric of the KNN graph. This support many distance metrics.

There is another argument `target_metric` that only support euclidean and categorical.

From your question it seems that support of more `target_metric` options is actually what you are looking for.
Feel free to show your interest for the addition of this feature [on this Github issue](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/4821).

Comment: I am a little confused. I believe `reducer = UMAP(metric='correlation')` is for the KNN graph. Please correct me if I am mistaken. This is what I was trying, I posted the reference from help, but the output shown is same for `eculidean`, `cosine` and `correlation`.